# how to find property and change value in QtQuick

Tags: python, pyqt, qml, qt-quick

how to find property **color** and change value for **Text** element in my qtquick project?
content on my.qml file.

```
Rectangle {
    width: 300
    height: 200

    Text {
        x: 12
        y: 34
        color:red
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to set objectName property like below:

```
Rectangle {
    width: 300
    height: 200

    Text {
      objectName: "text1"  
               x: 12
               y: 34
               color: "red"
    }  
}
```

now you can find and access to element and property.
for example, i find color in Text element and change to green:

```
view = QDeclarativeView(QUrl('widget.qml'),parent = object)
property = QDeclarativeProperty(view.rootObject().findChild(QDeclarativeItem, name="text1"),"color")
property.write("green")
```